# Hopscotch Cryptograph

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, cipher

With a little squinting, you should be able to discern a message which runs from the top to the bottom of the text box below.  (I have indicated the column with a little arrow.)  That is the visible message.

But the visible message is just a cover for a hidden message.  Can you figure out how to reveal the hidden message?

```
                         |                  
                         |                  
                         V                  
                    ┏━┳━┳━┳━┓               
                    ┃J┃O┃M┃O┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃B┃O┃A┃R┃D┃             
            ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛             
            ┃G┃A┃L┃L┃E┃R┃Y┃                 
            ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                        ┃B┃U┃T┃             
                      ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓         
                      ┃R┃E┃F┃O┃R┃M┃         
                ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛         
                ┃E┃A┃R┃T┃H┃                 
                ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓       
                      ┃G┃U┃N┃S┃H┃O┃T┃       
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛       
                    ┃T┃I┃M┃E┃S┃             
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃W┃A┃S┃T┃E┃           
                      ┣━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
                      ┃O┃N┃                 
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━┫                 
                  ┃A┃R┃T┃S┃                 
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓           
                      ┃P┃A┃N┃E┃L┃           
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
                  ┃D┃E┃A┃R┃                 
                  ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                  ┃R┃E┃C┃E┃N┃T┃             
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛             
                ┃H┃E┃A┃R┃T┃                 
                ┗━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┓         
                        ┃H┃E┃A┃R┃T┃         
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛         
                  ┃M┃I┃L┃E┃S┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                    ┃D┃E┃F┃R┃O┃S┃T┃         
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛         
                    ┃H┃E┃A┃R┃T┃             
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                    ┃S┃A┃I┃D┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃M┃I┃L┃E┃S┃             
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                        ┃E┃A┃S┃T┃           
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓       
                        ┃D┃I┃R┃E┃C┃T┃       
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛       
                  ┃A┃B┃O┃A┃R┃D┃             
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃M┃I┃L┃E┃S┃           
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                      ┃F┃O┃R┃M┃E┃R┃         
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛         
                        ┃F┃E┃L┃T┃           
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
                  ┃M┃E┃A┃N┃                 
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                    ┃S┃T┃A┃R┃               
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                  ┃C┃E┃N┃T┃E┃R┃             
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓       
                      ┃A┃U┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃       
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛       
                  ┃C┃O┃U┃R┃S┃E┃             
                  ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                  ┃Q┃U┃I┃E┃T┃               
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                ┃C┃H┃A┃R┃M┃                 
                ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃B┃R┃O┃A┃D┃               
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                ┃R┃E┃L┃A┃Y┃S┃               
                ┗━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓ 
                        ┃B┃A┃C┃T┃E┃R┃I┃A┃L┃ 
                ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛ 
                ┃T┃H┃R┃E┃E┃                 
                ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃B┃E┃I┃N┃G┃               
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓     
                      ┃H┃A┃N┃G┃O┃V┃E┃R┃     
                ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛     
                ┃Q┃U┃I┃E┃T┃                 
                ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                      ┃H┃U┃T┃S┃             
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                  ┃T┃H┃E┃R┃E┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃T┃H┃E┃R┃E┃             
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┓     
                        ┃M┃O┃N┃O┃S┃K┃I┃     
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛     
                        ┃A┃S┃I┃D┃E┃         
              ┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛         
              ┃S┃I┃G┃N┃E┃D┃                 
              ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃A┃N┃G┃E┃R┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                    ┃L┃A┃S┃T┃               
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                      ┃M┃O┃D┃E┃L┃S┃         
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛         
                        ┃M┃E┃A┃T┃           
                ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
                ┃T┃H┃E┃R┃E┃                 
      ┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
      ┃V┃I┃N┃A┃I┃G┃R┃E┃T┃T┃E┃               
      ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                      ┃S┃H┃A┃D┃E┃           
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                      ┃D┃I┃R┃E┃C┃T┃         
              ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛         
              ┃L┃A┃Y┃M┃E┃N┃                 
              ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃T┃O┃U┃G┃H┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃A┃S┃I┃D┃E┃             
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                    ┃A┃R┃T┃S┃               
              ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
              ┃R┃E┃C┃E┃N┃T┃                 
              ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫                 
                ┃T┃O┃U┃G┃H┃                 
                ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                      ┃P┃O┃S┃T┃             
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                    ┃T┃R┃U┃C┃K┃S┃           
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛           
                  ┃R┃A┃N┃G┃E┃               
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                ┃P┃E┃A┃C┃H┃                 
                ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━┫                 
                    ┃E┃A┃T┃                 
                    ┣━╋━╋━┫                 
                    ┃R┃A┃W┃                 
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┓         
                      ┃R┃O┃S┃T┃E┃R┃         
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛         
                      ┃H┃U┃T┃S┃             
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓         
                      ┃S┃L┃I┃G┃H┃T┃         
                ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛         
                ┃A┃R┃M┃E┃D┃                 
                ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃E┃A┃R┃T┃H┃               
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                      ┃S┃E┃L┃D┃O┃M┃         
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛         
                        ┃N┃O┃               
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃M┃E┃D┃I┃A┃             
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫             
                    ┃R┃A┃T┃E┃S┃             
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                  ┃N┃I┃G┃H┃T┃               
                  ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                  ┃D┃I┃R┃E┃C┃T┃             
                  ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫             
                  ┃S┃L┃I┃G┃H┃T┃             
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫             
                      ┃N┃A┃M┃E┃             
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫             
                    ┃E┃A┃R┃T┃H┃             
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓       
                        ┃D┃E┃V┃O┃T┃E┃       
                      ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛       
                      ┃C┃E┃N┃T┃E┃R┃         
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛         
                    ┃O┃W┃N┃                 
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                    ┃N┃A┃M┃E┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                    ┃P┃L┃A┃N┃E┃             
              ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛             
              ┃S┃T┃E┃A┃D┃Y┃                 
              ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┫                 
                    ┃N┃A┃B┃                 
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                      ┃M┃E┃A┃N┃             
                ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                ┃S┃L┃I┃G┃H┃T┃               
                ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                    ┃S┃O┃U┃R┃C┃E┃           
              ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
              ┃R┃E┃F┃O┃R┃M┃                 
              ┗━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓           
                      ┃E┃A┃R┃T┃H┃           
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                        ┃N┃O┃T┃E┃S┃         
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛         
                        ┃S┃I┃T┃             
                      ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃R┃A┃N┃G┃E┃           
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛           
                    ┃A┃G┃R┃E┃E┃             
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃H┃E┃A┃R┃T┃           
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                        ┃T┃H┃I┃N┃G┃         
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫         
                        ┃H┃A┃T┃E┃D┃         
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫         
                        ┃E┃A┃R┃T┃H┃         
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓       
                  ┃E┃L┃E┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃S┃       
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛       
                    ┃B┃R┃O┃A┃D┃             
                ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                ┃V┃I┃T┃A┃M┃I┃N┃S┃           
              ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
              ┃A┃S┃L┃E┃E┃P┃                 
            ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
            ┃T┃R┃I┃A┃N┃G┃L┃E┃               
            ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                      ┃S┃E┃A┃T┃             
            ┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫             
            ┃T┃R┃A┃N┃S┃A┃X┃L┃E┃             
            ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃A┃S┃I┃D┃E┃           
              ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
              ┃N┃A┃M┃E┃L┃Y┃                 
              ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓           
                        ┃S┃T┃A┃R┃           
                        ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                        ┃T┃H┃R┃E┃E┃         
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛         
                  ┃U┃P┃S┃E┃T┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                    ┃R┃E┃M┃A┃I┃N┃           
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫           
                        ┃S┃E┃A┃T┃           
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛           
                    ┃S┃T┃O┃P┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                    ┃R┃I┃F┃L┃E┃S┃           
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫           
                    ┃P┃L┃A┃N┃E┃S┃           
                ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛           
                ┃B┃E┃G┃I┃N┃                 
                ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                      ┃S┃A┃W┃               
              ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┛               
              ┃S┃I┃L┃E┃N┃T┃                 
              ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
              ┃T┃E┃D┃I┃O┃U┃S┃               
              ┗━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                      ┃T┃R┃U┃T┃H┃S┃         
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛         
                      ┃E┃A┃S┃T┃             
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓           
                      ┃P┃L┃A┃N┃E┃           
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓         
                        ┃O┃V┃E┃R┃T┃         
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛         
                    ┃T┃H┃R┃E┃E┃             
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                    ┃E┃N┃D┃S┃               
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                      ┃M┃E┃A┃N┃S┃           
                    ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫           
                    ┃G┃A┃R┃D┃E┃N┃           
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫           
                        ┃T┃I┃E┃D┃           
                  ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛           
                  ┃N┃I┃G┃H┃T┃S┃             
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                      ┃W┃A┃S┃               
                      ┗━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                        ┃T┃H┃E┃R┃E┃         
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┛         
                    ┃L┃U┃M┃P┃               
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┓       
                  ┃R┃E┃D┃U┃C┃T┃I┃O┃N┃       
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛       
                ┃M┃I┃L┃E┃S┃                 
                ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━┫                 
                    ┃S┃I┃T┃                 
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                    ┃F┃I┃B┃E┃R┃             
                    ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┓     
                        ┃U┃N┃C┃L┃E┃A┃R┃     
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛     
                    ┃T┃H┃I┃N┃G┃             
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                    ┃M┃A┃L┃E┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━┳━┓           
                    ┃I┃N┃D┃E┃E┃D┃           
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┛           
                      ┃D┃A┃D┃               
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                  ┃T┃H┃I┃N┃G┃               
                  ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                  ┃C┃R┃E┃D┃I┃T┃             
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                      ┃A┃D┃D┃               
                  ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                  ┃L┃O┃V┃E┃S┃               
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                ┃N┃O┃T┃E┃S┃                 
                ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                    ┃N┃O┃T┃E┃               
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                  ┃B┃O┃A┃R┃D┃               
                  ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                      ┃N┃O┃                 
        ┏━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━┫                 
        ┃P┃R┃E┃D┃A┃T┃O┃R┃Y┃                 
        ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃B┃E┃G┃I┃N┃               
                  ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                    ┃H┃A┃T┃E┃               
                    ┣━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                    ┃I┃T┃S┃                 
                    ┗━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┳━┳━┓       
                      ┃R┃E┃B┃U┃I┃L┃D┃       
              ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┻━┻━┻━┛       
              ┃L┃A┃R┃G┃E┃L┃Y┃               
              ┗━┻━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                  ┃D┃E┃A┃F┃                 
                  ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━┳━┓             
                        ┃I┃T┃S┃             
                ┏━┳━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                ┃M┃A┃R┃I┃N┃E┃               
                ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                  ┃S┃N┃A┃P┃                 
                ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                ┃S┃I┃G┃N┃E┃D┃               
                ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┫               
                      ┃A┃R┃E┃               
                      ┣━╋━╋━╋━┓             
                      ┃S┃P┃A┃N┃             
                ┏━┳━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛             
                ┃S┃T┃A┃Y┃E┃D┃               
                ┣━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛               
                ┃O┃U┃G┃H┃T┃                 
                ┗━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┓               
                  ┃S┃E┃T┃U┃P┃               
                  ┗━┻━┻━╋━╋━╋━┳━┳━┓         
                        ┃I┃D┃E┃A┃S┃         
                    ┏━┳━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛         
                    ┃V┃E┃T┃O┃E┃D┃           
                  ┏━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━╋━┛           
                  ┃S┃L┃A┃Y┃E┃R┃             
                  ┗━┻━┻━┻━┻━┻━┛
```

*Credit:  Visible message is composed of excerpts from the poem "Nature" by Bianca Stone.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that the message can be revealed by

> finding the most common anagram of each word reading across. Then, that anagram is put back in the boxes to reveal a new message reading down.

For example:

> The first few words are JOMO; BOARD; GALLERY; BUT; REFORM; EARTH; GUNSHOT; TIMES. Anagrams of each of these are MOJO; BROAD; ALLERGY; TUB; FORMER; HEART. SHOTGUN; ITEMS. The new letters in the marked column spell "JOY TO THE...".

I haven't done most of it, but the message appears to be:

> the lyrics of Joy To The World:
>
>  *Joy to the world, the lord is come*
>  *Let earth receive her king*
>  *Let every heart prepare him room*
>  *and heaven and nature sing*
>  *and heaven and nature sing*
>  *and heaven, and heaven, and nature sing*
>
>  (There are way too many anagrams to do by hand in any reasonable amount of time, but each word does have its required letter, and I checked a few intermediate words.)

Comment: Excellent work, Deusovi.  In your first spoiler box, would you mind changing "of each word" to "of each horizontal word"?  That might give added clarity to people who are having trouble seeing it.

Comment: @SlowMagic Done!

Comment: going down vertically from the arrow I found "Maybe humans are the failed AI (artificial intelligence) of nature maybe nature made something it thought would tend the garden maybe humans are the complex systems of a natural order that must build and destroy itself in perpetuity". is this on purpose?

Comment: @ZitianYang Yes, that is the "visible message" mentioned in the question itself.

Comment: @Deusovi ok then